# How can I find out when this Java API change happened?

Tags: java

At some point `java.lang.Override` started to be available for use with implementations of methods declared in interfaces.  I'm pretty sure there was a time when it just worked for overrides of methods defined in superclasses.

How can I find out when (i.e. at which version) this change happened?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use of the `@Override` annotation on methods that are implemented from interfaces and not overridden from a superclass is a new feature in Java 6. See [@Override specification changes in Java 6](http://dertompson.com/2008/01/25/override-specification-changes-in-java-6/):

> Between Java 5 and Java 6 changes to
>   the specification of @Override have
>   been made. In Java 6 it is possible to
>   add the @Override annotation to
>   methods that implement methods of an
>   interface which is not allowed in Java
>   5.
>
> I noticed the difference when a friend
>   told me that he had to remove all the
>   @Override annotations to make his Java
>   6 project compile with Java 5.
>
> The interesting thing is that there is
>   no documentation about this change.
>   The API specification of @Override is
>   exactly the same in both Java
>   versions. I found out that this was
>   forgotten by Sun developers. [Peter
>   AhÃ©, a former developer at Sun, calls
>   it the @Override Snafu](http://blogs.oracle.com/ahe/entry/override_snafu).

Comment: This contradicts the JLS, as linked to from the Java6 docs: "Note that if a method overrides a method from a superinterface but not from a superclass, using @Override will cause a compile-time error. "

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you'd find this out, but it happened between 5 and 6. (i.e. it's forbidden in 5 but accepted in 6.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "officially" find out because [someone at Sun messed up](http://blogs.oracle.com/ahe/entry/override_snafu) and did not update the specification in the API doc of `java.lang.Override` when the implementation was changed, and apparently changing the specification after the release is not allowed.